# Can Wild Magic Surges restore hit points and spell slots to a Simulacrum of a Wild Magic Sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hit-points, wild-magic, spell-slots

Some effects of the [Wild Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) table (PHB, p. 104) make the Sorcerer regain hit points or spell slots:

> 15-16:  For the next minute, you regain 5 hit points at the start of each of your turns.
>
> 39-40:  You regain 2d10 hit points.
>
> 59-60:  You regain your lowest-level expended spell slot.

The relevant rules about Simulacrums from the [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell are:

> The simulacrum lacks the ability to learn or become more powerful, so it never increases its level or other abilities, nor can it regain expended spell slots. If the simulacrum is damaged, you can repair it in an alchemical laboratory, using rare herbs and minerals worth 100 gp per hit point it regains.

But here, can a Simulacrum of a Wild Magic Sorcerer benefit from getting one of the above surges? In other words, which is ***more specific*** between Simulacrum's rules on spell slots and healing, or the above Wild Magic surge effects?

Comment: Related for [healing magic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59781/33707), [second wind](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107590/33707), and [regeneration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121755/simulacrum-with-regeneration).

Comment: Another one: [Can a Simulacrum of a sorcerer regain its sorcery points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122502/can-a-simulacrum-of-a-sorcerer-regain-its-sorcery-points)

Answer (score 10):

## Hit point recovery can only happen through the alchemical process

> If the simulacrum is damaged, you can **repair** it in an alchemical laboratory, using rare herbs and minerals worth 100 gp per hit point it regains.

#### Repair not heal

First note that this does not say heal it says *repair*. Though treated as a normal creature it is still a being made of ice and snow. It is that reason that it likely has a special way to repair it.

#### Allowing other forms of healing means that the alchemical process would be useless

This statement must preclude other forms of regaining hit points otherwise it is meaningless. Even though it does not say so explicitly, the above method is clearly meant to be the only way to regain hit points for a simulacrum.

It does not say that potions or healing magic or rest doesn't work for example, but if they were possible then the expensive complicated process for healing would be meaningless and there would be no point in including it. Sleep especially makes this meaningless because it is free and available to every creature/class and allows for healing completely. *Why would anybody ever pay 100gp per hit point if they could sleep or use any of the myriad of other methods for regaining hit points available?* This logic also applies to traits or features that let you heal.

#### Simulacrum is more specific than Wild Magic; Wild Magic is no more specific than any other healing ability.

There is nothing that makes wild surges a more specific effect than any other healing ability. If the simulacrum restriction was not more specific than all healing spells and abilities would work on it, and as per the above, would thus make the restriction meaningless.

Take for example *cure light wounds* which says:

> A creature you touch regains  a number of hit points...

It uses the exact same language as the wild magic surge and thus if wild magic surge worked then *cure light wounds* or any other healing spell or magical ability would as well. And if all those things work then there is no point in even having the alternate healing method.

Thus, we must read the simulacrum restriction as being more specific otherwise it would be pointless.

#### RAI agrees

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/801539885861437440) supports this logic as well:

> To restore hit points to a simulacrum, you must use the costly alchemical procedure mentioned in the spell.

Which means Crawford also implicitly agrees that the simulacrum ability is more specific by extension.

## Spell slots cannot be regained by any means

The same logic applies to the spell slot restriction. *Simulacrum* says:

> The simulacrum lacks the ability to learn or become more powerful, so it [...] [can't] regain expended spell slots.

When it says that it can't regain spell slots, it means just that. It doesn't say can't regain spell slots except by this and this feature.

This is more specific than abilities that allow you to regain spell slots by default; otherwise the restriction wouldn't function at all. Whereas most things can recover spell slots, a simulacrum may not by any means. If it didn't override  other methods of recovering spell slots then it would be pointless to even write it, thus it is by necessity, more specific than those abilities.

#### RAI again agrees

Jeremy Crawford again supports this interpretation [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1011342543873761280):

> Simulacrum—the spell's creation can't gain levels or regain expended spell slots (RAW). The creation is meant to be unable to regain use of any of its features that it expends (RAI).

**Thus, no hit points or spell slots can be recovered using wild magic.**

Comment: Wouldn't it have been lovely if they had the forethought to add 1 additional word to that passage? "you can *only* repair it in an alchemical laboratory"... funny how one simple change clears up pretty much any ambiguity.

Comment: @Slagmoth Right?! Seems like a *really* easy errata as well. But they are loathe to errata anything that isn't simply blatantly wrong.

Comment: Another relevant Crawford tweet: "[Simulacrum—the spell's creation can't gain levels or regain expended spell slots (RAW). The creation is meant to be unable to regain use of any of its features that it expends (RAI).](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1011342543873761280) [...] [There's a good chance it will be (errataed). A simulacrum is meant to lose efficacy over time, essentially running out of juice, until only at-will abilities remain.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1011373574521647104)"

Comment: I don't get this comment: "And if wild magic was somehow more specific there would literally be no restriction in place and everything could restore spell slots to the simulacrum" - why can't wild magic be more specific than resting? (Your conclusion is valid, but this line is strange to me)

Comment: @SeriousBri: Because all the abilities that I could find that restore spell slots (aka resting and this basically) use the exact same language. No reason to think that one is more specific than the other. They are equal. Not sure how to rephrase it such that it is more clear. Do you have a thought on this?

Comment: FWIW, we have a similar/related answer and question about healing and simulacrums. I'll get you a link.  [If you are interested](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107590/22566)